# Minimax function not working for connect 4

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax, game-theory

I am trying to implement a computer AI version of connect 4 in java using the minimax algorithm.  For the task I created a "Node" class which begins with a single board state and then recursively creates more nodes up to a specified depth.  It then scores each node with a 1 as a win a 0 as a draw or max depth.  Finally, the I use the minimax algorithem to pick which move to use in the function "getColumn()".  Here is my code

```
package ai;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Node {
    public ArrayList < Node > nodeList = new ArrayList < Node > ();
    private int[][] board; // Represents board, 0 is empty space, 1 is player 1, 2 is computer
    private int turn; // Current turn, 1 is player, 2 is computer

    // Node constructor, creates tree of possible game states
    public Node(int[][] board, int depth, int turn) {
        this.board = board;
        this.turn = turn;

        if (depth > 0 && result(turn) == -1) {
            int[][] copy = new int[7][6];

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            copy[i] = board[i].clone();

            int[] cols = getAvailCols(board);

            for (int col: cols) {
                int y = placeBlock(col, turn, copy);
                nodeList.add(new Node(copy, depth - 1, turn == 1 ? 2 : 1));
                copy[col][y] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Returns 0 for draw, 1 for win, -1 for no result
    private int result(int currTurn) {
        int horCount = 1;
        int verCount = 1;
        int ldiaCount = 1;
        int rdiaCount = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                for (int countX = x + 1; countX < 7; countX++) {
                    if (board[countX][y] == currTurn) horCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countX = x - 1; countX >= 0; countX--) {
                    if (board[countX][y] == currTurn) horCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countY = y + 1; countY < 6; countY++) {
                    if (board[x][countY] == currTurn) verCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countY = y - 1; countY >= 0; countY--) {
                    if (board[x][countY] == currTurn) verCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countX = x + 1, countY = y + 1; countX < 7 && countY < 6; countX++, countY++) {
                    if (board[countX][countY] == currTurn) rdiaCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countX = x - 1, countY = y - 1; countX >= 0 && countY >= 0; countX--, countY--) {
                    if (board[countX][countY] == currTurn) rdiaCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countX = x + 1, countY = y - 1; countX < 7 && countY >= 0; countX++, countY--) {
                    if (board[countX][countY] == currTurn) ldiaCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                for (int countX = x - 1, countY = y + 1; countX >= 0 && countY < 6; countX--, countY++) {
                    if (board[countX][countY] == currTurn) ldiaCount++;
                    else break;
                }

                if (horCount >= 4 || verCount >= 4 || ldiaCount >= 4 || rdiaCount >= 4) {
                    return 1;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        if (board[i][j] == 0) return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Puts chip into a column
    private int placeBlock(int x, int turn, int[][] checkboard) {
        int y = 0;

        while (y < 5 && checkboard[x][y + 1] == 0)
        y++;

        checkboard[x][y] = turn;
        return y;
    }

    // Gets the score of a node
    private int score() {
        int result = result(turn);

        if (result == 0) return 0;
        else if (result == 1) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        else if (nodeList.size() > 0) {
            int score = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for (Node node: nodeList)
            score = Math.max(score, -node.score());

            return score;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int[] getAvailCols(int[][] checkboard) {
        ArrayList < Integer > list = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (checkboard[i][0] == 0) list.add(i);
        }

        int[] cols = new int[list.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            cols[i] = (int) list.get(i);
        }

        return cols;
    }

    // Only called for top node tell whichmove ai should take
    public int getColumn() {
        int[] cols = getAvailCols(board);
        int index = 0;
        int maxScore = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            if (nodeList.get(i).score() > maxScore) {
                maxScore = nodeList.get(i).score();
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return cols[index];
    }
}
```

In the board array:

- `0`s are empty space
- `1`s are the players chips
- `2`s are the ai's chips

I have run many tests however and the computer always seems to pick the left most column that is available even when the other player is about to win.  Could anyone explain how to fix this or what the problem is.  I am using a depth of 7 for my game at the moment.

Comment: I haven't analyzed your code in detail, but one thing that pops out is that you're using Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE together with unary negation. That doesn't work because -Integer.MIN_VALUE is still Integer.MIN_VALUE. I recommend using numbers like plus or minus one billion instead.

Comment: Also, I've never seen minimax done without an evaluation function (except for super simple games like tic tac toe which can be searched exhaustively).